# Azure web role remote desktop

Tags: for-loop, web, desktop

I would like to update or modify web of the my web apps setting . 
1. How to enable my web apps remote desktop ? 
2. is there any way we could update my web apps setting . Basically we need to make sure  Handler Mappin is enabled similar to below .

http://dotnetstock.com/technical/http-error-405-0-method-not-allowed-invalid-method-http-verb-when-posting-a-form-in-asp-net/

Thanks 
Ravi k

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. What have you tried so far? Please show your code.